# Integration of own fonts into the XSL/FOP

Tags: fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using FOP to generate PDF reports.
The problem is I need the DIN-Regular font instead of the default Times New Roman.
Can anybody tall me how to change the font?
I'm using fop-0.94.boc.02 version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is register the font and it's location in your config file, fop.xconf.

Like so:

```
<fonts>

  <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TTF</directory>  
  <font-triplet name="DIN-Regular" style="normal" weight="bold"/>

(...)

</fonts>
```

In your FOP code you should refer the font like so:

```
<fo:block font-size="11.5pt" font-family="DIN-Regular"> Content
</fo:block>
```

Currently FOP supports only TrueType fonts correctly, I think.

You also have to take a look at the style of the font, in order to include it in your triplet. Do this by opening and investigating your font.

Make sure to include -c fop.xconf when you call fop and you should be good to go!

Comment: Hi I would like add 'ubuntu-b-webfont'. How and where to add this config file. we use FOP version 0.95.0.0002 that comes with CQ5 by default.Please suggest .